# Running QgsZonalStatistics in PyQGIS script?

Tags: pyqgis, zonal-statistics

I have experienced a very bizarre issue with my PyQgis code. I simply want to load a raster and a vector layer to do zonal statistics, the first part works perfectly but for the zonal statistic I have got an error with this command:

`raster file = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(1).source()`

(AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'source')

The strange thing is that if I rerun only the second part of the code (ie. my layers are already loaded) the extension .source() does not report any errors. This is still annoying since I am not able to write a loop with the full code and then use it for different layers.

Did anyone already experience this kind of issue?

Here is the code,

```
os.chdir("C:\Projet")
###          Part I
##           load vector layer
vbaselayer = QgsVectorLayer("county_save_as_lamhert_onlyUS.shp", "basemap", "ogr")
##           load and project the raster layer

os.system('gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:102004 -of GTiff NETCDF:"rhum.2m.2000.nc":rhum rhum_projection.tif')
humidity = "rhum_projection.tif"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(humidity)
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(humidity,"hum2000")
rlayer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vbaselayer,"2000.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")
year = 2000
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("{}.shp".format(year), "county", "ogr")
vlayer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
###          Part II
##           zonal statistics
id = 1
while id < 365:
    vectorlayer=qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(0)
    rasterfile = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(1).source()
    zonalstats = qgis.analysis.QgsZonalStatistics(vectorlayer,rasterfile,str(id),id)
    zonalstats.calculateStatistics(None)
    id += 1
```

Comment: I guess you meant `raster_file = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layers()[1].source()`, didn't you?

Comment: Not really, is there any difference? The full code for zonal stat is :
`vectorlayer=qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(0)

rasterfile = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(1).source()

zonalstats = qgis.analysis.QgsZonalStatistics(vectorlayer,rasterfile,str(1),1)

zonalstats.calculateStatistics(None)
`

Comment: Didn't know about that way to access layers, but it works. So, how many layers are loaded when you run the line of code you posted in the question?

Comment: Only two, the first one is the vector layer and the second is the raster one. So the code stop after having load the 2 layers, but if i rerun only the second part it will work...

Comment: Weird. You should then be able to access the second layer in the ToC via `layer(1)`. Could you post how are you loading your layers, i.e., provide a reproducible code snippet?

Comment: I edited my first post

Comment: Are you getting True from both calls to `isValid()`?

Comment: yes, both of them

Comment: You're running this script out of QGIS (i.e., as a stand-alone script), right?

Comment: I don't think so, I am using the python extension.

Comment: I mean, are you running your script from within the QGIS Python console (in the QGIS GUI), or in an OS Python console (importing PyQGIS libs)?

Comment: I am using the QGIS GUI. An other weird thing, I thought that maybe the error occured because python would go "faster" than QGIS mapcanvas so I added `print "whatever"`before the command with .source() (in order to gain some times) and now the error is different:

QgsZonalStatistics(QgsZonalStatistics): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsRasterLayer'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script works for me in the QGIS Python console:

```
vLayer = QgsVectorLayer("/path/to/vector.shp","my vector","ogr")
rasterPath = "/path/to/raster.tif"
rLayer = QgsRasterLayer(rasterPath,"my raster")
if not ( vLayer.isValid() and rLayer.isValid() ):
    print "Error loading layers..."

band=1
from qgis.analysis import QgsZonalStatistics
zonalstats = QgsZonalStatistics( vLayer, rasterPath, str(band), band )
zonalstats.calculateStatistics( None )
```

I would suggest you to try this very simple script and then extend it with your own logic.

---

By the way, there are strange things in your script.

You don't need to put these lines inside a while loop:

```
vectorlayer=qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(0)
rasterfile = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(1).source()
```

You already have the vector layer in `vlayer` and the raster source in `rlayer.source()`. Even more, you also don't need to add the layers to the registry before using them.

Your while loop could be simply:

```
id = 1
rsource = rlayer.source()
while id < 365:
    zonalstats = qgis.analysis.QgsZonalStatistics(vlayer,rsource,str(id),id)
    zonalstats.calculateStatistics(None)
    id += 1
```