# PyQGIS error when running zonal statistics?

Tags: qgis-3, zonal-statistics, pyqgis-3

I want to extract the sum of my raster cell values with a specific area through zonal statistics and have prepared the following code (see below). When I run the code I get the following error message (see bottom).

Any suggestions?

```py
from qgis.analysis import QgsZonalStatistics

#specify polygon shapefile vector
polygonLayer = QgsVectorLayer('C:/Users/Anna Nilsson/Desktop/AIRPOLIM-ES/GIS data/Kenya/cpp_KE_buf1.gpkg', 'zonepolygons', "ogr") 

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(polygonLayer)

# specify raster filename
rasterFilePath = 'C:/Users/Anna Nilsson/Desktop/AIRPOLIM-ES/GIS data/Kenya/KEN_worldpop/KEN_popmap15adj_v2b.tif'

# usage - QgsZonalStatistics (QgsVectorLayer *polygonLayer, const QString &rasterFile, const QString &attributePrefix="", int rasterBand=1)
zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (polygonLayer, rasterFilePath, 'pre-', 1,QgsZonalStatistics.Sum)
zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
TypeError: QgsZonalStatistics(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
  overload 2: argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
  overload 3: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'
```

Comment: have a look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136220/running-qgszonalstatistics-in-pyqgis-script

Answer (score 3):

Error message says "`QgsZonalStatistics` has different usages, and one of the argument types for every usage is wrong."

If you look at [QgsZonalStatistics Class Reference](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsZonalStatistics.html#a39bec2efdb6a192b641e570abfea122b) you will see that the second parameter has to be a raster layer reference, not a raster path. The usage you specify in your code belongs to QGIS 2.x. In QGIS 3.x, you have to define a raster reference by `QgsRasterLayer` and pass as an argument to `QgsZonalStatistics` (constructor) method.

```py
from qgis.analysis import QgsZonalStatistics

polygonLayer = QgsVectorLayer('C:/Users/Anna Nilsson/Desktop/AIRPOLIM-ES/GIS data/Kenya/cpp_KE_buf1.gpkg', 'zonepolygons', "ogr")     
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(polygonLayer)

rasterFilePath = 'C:/Users/Anna Nilsson/Desktop/AIRPOLIM-ES/GIS data/Kenya/KEN_worldpop/KEN_popmap15adj_v2b.tif'

### ADD NEXT TWO LINES TO CHANGE "rasterFilePath" INTO "rasterLayer"
rasterLayer = QgsRasterLayer(rasterFilePath, "Raster Layer")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rasterLayer)

zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (polygonLayer, rasterLayer , 'pre-', 1,QgsZonalStatistics.Sum)
zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
```

Comment: Many thanks, this seem to work better. Now I came across an additional issue; my input vector layer is a temporary file and has therefore not have any location. How can I call a temporary layer in PyQGIS?

Comment: Please review the answer in this post: [Getting layer by name in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/136861/29431).